# Is it possible to make some shell calls automatically when entering a directory?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

Just like a local `.bashrc` file, which is `source`d every time I entered the directory.
How to make this work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use an alias:

```
$ echo 'echo "execute something for $PWD"' > tests/.cdrc
$ _cd()
{
    \cd $1
    [ -r .cdrc ] && . .cdrc
}
```

this function first change to the dir specified as argument, check if the file `.cdrc` is readable and source it.

```
$ alias cd=_cd
```

Then

```
$ cd tests
execute something for /path/to/tests
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I guess OP want to _monitor_ a dir IMHO

Comment: I guess OP wants >sourced every time I entered the directory

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I am trying to do, what's strange is that it says there is no `.cdrc` file or directory. Could you explain the second line of _cd function to me, I'm new here. Thank you.

Comment: @flyingfoxlee If tests to see if the named file exists and is readable and if so attempts to `source` it as shell commands.

Comment: +1 but you will need to rig `pushd` and perhaps `popd` also for orthogonality and least astinishment.

Comment: Thanks, learned a new trick that `.` would souce a file in bash, seems it's has no such meaning in zsh. @dmckee

Comment: @flyingfoxlee:  `zsh` does have the `.` command and it means the same thing as it does in `bash`.  The `source` command is a synonym for the `.` command.  See the `zshbuiltins` man page for details.

Comment: @flyingfoxlee:  see my answer for an approach that won't break tab completion

Comment: There's no need for the alias.  Just call the function `cd` and invoke the builtin with `command`.

Answer (score 3):

`bash` and `zsh` (and probably many other shells) have a feature that allows you to run an arbitrary command before the prompt is displayed.  You can use this to source a `.dirrc` file, and it won't break tab completion.

Here's how to do it in `bash`:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='
if [ "${PREV}" != "$(pwd -P)" ]; then
    if [ -r .dirrc ]; then
        . ./.dirrc
    fi
    PREV=$(pwd -P)
fi
'
```

From the `bash` man page:

> `PROMPT_COMMAND`: If set, the value is executed as a command prior to issuing each primary prompt.

This is how to do it in `zsh` (see the `zshmisc` man page):

```
precmd() {
    if [ "${PREV}" != "$(pwd -P)" ]; then
        if [ -r .dirrc ]; then
            . ./.dirrc
        fi
        PREV=$(pwd -P)
    fi
}
```

Comment: Great solution, What's the `PREV` variable doing here?

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it doesn't satisfy the asker's "every time I enter a directory" requirement. :) (Sorry, couldn't resist.) That is, it won't work as expected in the command sequence: `cd foo && make bar`, since the enter script will be executed after the `make` and not before it; it might mean that environment variables were not set as expected.

Comment: @rici: touché!  :)  I think it depends on flyingfoxlee's definition of "enter a directory".  I had assumed that it meant being at a prompt in that directory, but perhaps I'm wrong.

Comment: @flyingfoxlee:  Because the command is run every time the prompt is shown, it'll run over and over even if you stay in the same directory.  The `PREV` command prevents `.dirrc` from being sourced multiple times while you're still in the same directory (it'll only source `.dirrc` when you change directories).  For a demo of what happens without it, try `PROMPT_COMMAND='echo foo'` and simply hit enter a few times.

Comment: I see, is `precmd() {
    if [ "${PREV}" != "$(pwd -P)" ]; then
        if   [ -r .dirrc ]; then
            . ./.dirrc
        fi
        PREV=$(pwd -P)
    fi
}`
` a better one. This time, the `PREV` variable is updated every time I switched a directory, not just on those directories that has a `.dirrc` file in them.

Comment: @flyingfoxlee:  Good point; I updated my answer.  (The old way still works, but your way is slightly more efficient because it avoids looking for `.dirrc` every time the prompt is displayed when in a directory without a `.dirrc` file.)